# How to align center the icon next to the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, icons

I'm working on the palette project and what I'm trying to do is to put icon next to Beige text and place it on the right side.

However, when I put icon next to beige, the palette layout  started to break up and icon is not aligned in the center with text.

How to fix this problem?

Below image will find how I want to do it.
[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.board {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.board-nav-indicator {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
  /*background-color:red;*/
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  transition:all 0.3s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  z-index:1;
}
[data-page='0'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(0);
}
[data-page='1'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
[data-page='2'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(200%);
}

.board-nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.board-pages {
  position:absolute;
  top:75px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.board-page {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.4s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #262931;
}

.grid-row-theme .grid-item-theme {
  max-width: 130px;
}

#align-left {
  float: left;
  color: #747474;
}

#align-right {
  float: right;
  color: #9CC8E3;
}

.grid-item {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-item-theme {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-row {
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.grid-row .grid-item {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:110px;
}

.grid-item-content {
  text-align:left;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size:0.3rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}


.pick-palette img{
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

#dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 6% 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Omnibag Project</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body> 

<div class="board-pages">

      <div class="board-page">

        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="dropdown-menu">Warm<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></div>

        <div class="trending-above-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Trending</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>   

        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-beige">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />   
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Beige
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-camel">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Camel
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-salmon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Salmon Pink
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-navajo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Navajo White
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-niagara">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Niagara
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-primrose">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Primrose
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lapis">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lapis Blue
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Newly added</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div> 


        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-pale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Pale Blue
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-moss">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Moss Green
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-melon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Melon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-chiffon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Chiffon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-island">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Island
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-dogwood">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Dogwood
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-greenery">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Greenery
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">All Warm Colors</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>    
        <div class="grid-row">

          <div class="grid-item grid-ivory">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Ivory
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-honeydew">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Honeydew
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lavender">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lavender
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-canary">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Canary
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-hazelnut">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Hazelnut
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-kale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Kale
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-sharkskin">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content sharkskin">
              Sharkskin
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.typekit.net/hoc0zbs.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

  <script>

    $(".board-pages .grid-item").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });

    $(".board-pages .grid-item-pattern-board").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });
 

  </script>
```

Comment: Consider simplifying your code sample. Maybe put just one item where the problem exists. I don't think you need to post the entire layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could help:

CSS

```
 .grid-item-content {
   height: 26px;
   line-height: 26px;
   position: relative;
}
.grid-item-content i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.board {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.board-nav-indicator {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
  /*background-color:red;*/
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  transition:all 0.3s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  z-index:1;
}
[data-page='0'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(0);
}
[data-page='1'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
[data-page='2'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(200%);
}

.board-nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.board-pages {
  position:absolute;
  top:75px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.board-page {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.4s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #262931;
}

.grid-row-theme .grid-item-theme {
  max-width: 130px;
}

#align-left {
  float: left;
  color: #747474;
}

#align-right {
  float: right;
  color: #9CC8E3;
}

.grid-item {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-item-theme {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-row {
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.grid-row .grid-item {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:110px;
}

.grid-item-content {
  text-align:left;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size:0.3rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}


.pick-palette img{
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

#dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 6% 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.grid-item-content {
   height: 26px;
   line-height: 26px;
   position: relative;
}
.grid-item-content i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Omnibag Project</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body> 

<div class="board-pages">

      <div class="board-page">

        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="dropdown-menu">Warm<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></div>

        <div class="trending-above-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Trending</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>   

        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-beige">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />   
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Beige
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-camel">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Camel
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-salmon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Salmon Pink
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-navajo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Navajo White
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-niagara">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Niagara
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-primrose">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Primrose
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lapis">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lapis Blue
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Newly added</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div> 


        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-pale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Pale Blue
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-moss">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Moss Green
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-melon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Melon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-chiffon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Chiffon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-island">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Island
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-dogwood">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Dogwood
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-greenery">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Greenery
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">All Warm Colors</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>    
        <div class="grid-row">

          <div class="grid-item grid-ivory">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Ivory
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-honeydew">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Honeydew
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lavender">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lavender
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-canary">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Canary
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-hazelnut">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Hazelnut
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-kale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Kale
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-sharkskin">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content sharkskin">
              Sharkskin
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.typekit.net/hoc0zbs.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

  <script>

    $(".board-pages .grid-item").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });

    $(".board-pages .grid-item-pattern-board").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });
 

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The font size of the icon is larger than the text. So you can reduce your font size of the icon. Also to position the icon to the right you can make it absolute to its container

This are the codes i edited try it. Hope it helps

```
.grid-item-content {
  text-align:left;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size: 0.3rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  position: relative;
}
.grid-item-content > i {
    font-size: 0.3rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It really helped!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, I think, would be to assign to the box wrapper property - "position: relative", and the tick icon inside of it: "position: absolute".
The following modification should probably work (it would be easier if you could make a fiddle of your code and put a link here):

```
.grid-row .grid-item {
    position: relative;
}

.grid-item-content i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set float right to the icon and set the exactly font-size needed to be aligned.

Be careful with the image, if the block is smaller than it, the image exceeds the block

```
.grid-item-content .more-icon{
    float: right;
    font-size: FONT SIZE YOU NEED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with some of the other answers I've seen, using `position: relative;` on the wrapper and `position: absolute;` on the icon. Something you'll run into, though, is now the text will run into the icon and either overlap or break onto the next line.

I would do what I've got here and add a `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and some `padding-right` to the wrapper as well so it doesn't run into the icon, but instead stops early and cuts it off when it's too long..

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.board {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.board-nav-indicator {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
  /*background-color:red;*/
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  transition:all 0.3s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  z-index:1;
}
[data-page='0'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(0);
}
[data-page='1'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
[data-page='2'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(200%);
}

.board-nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.board-pages {
  position:absolute;
  top:75px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.board-page {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.4s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #262931;
}

.grid-row-theme .grid-item-theme {
  max-width: 130px;
}

#align-left {
  float: left;
  color: #747474;
}

#align-right {
  float: right;
  color: #9CC8E3;
}

.grid-item {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-item-theme {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-row {
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.grid-row .grid-item {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:110px;
}

.grid-item-content {
  text-align:left;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size:0.3rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.pick-palette img{
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

#dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 6% 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.material-icons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: .45 !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Omnibag Project</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body> 

<div class="board-pages">

      <div class="board-page">

        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="dropdown-menu">Warm<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></div>

        <div class="trending-above-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Trending</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>   

        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-beige">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />   
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Beige
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-camel">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Here is a really long name
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-salmon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Salmon Pink
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-navajo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Navajo White
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-niagara">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Niagara
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-primrose">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Primrose
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lapis">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lapis Blue
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.typekit.net/hoc0zbs.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

  <script>

    $(".board-pages .grid-item").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });

    $(".board-pages .grid-item-pattern-board").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });
 

  </script>
```